# Drupal 6: How to use form_set_error on specific cell when using tablefield module

Tags: drupal-6

I need to validate that cell values are floats, that part is easy. What I'm not sure about is how to get form_set_error to highlight the offending cell and only that cell. Currently entering form_set_error('field_breakdown_table', ....) highlights all cells, obviously. I've tried crazy things like
"'field_breakdown_table']['widget']['default_value'][0]['tablefield']['cell_" . $row . "_" . $column . "'"
but haven't seen anything work yet. Has anyone ever gotten this to work?

Here is a link to the [tablefield module](http://drupal.org/project/tablefield)

Please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the solution I found for [this question](http://drupal.org/comment/reply/1297100#comment-5299838) (this is the issue I posted in the tablefield module issue queue) in the [form_set_error documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_set_error/6#comment-22698).